# Parallax sidebar scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, parallax

I just want to create a parallax sidebar like http://readwrite.com/.

Is there any plugin for that? 
or
Is that a custom parallax for just this site?

Comment: What do you mean by parallax?

Comment: so what is the name this effect?

Comment: you are right, it is parallax.

Answer (score 3):

After a few hours of experimenting and coding, I've finally come up with a very exposed solution that doesn't rely on fixed positions (or extensive jQuery plugins), but rather relies solely on **absolute positioning** using known offsets.

See it in action at: http://jsfiddle.net/LntUP/

The code that makes it happen:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var origTop = $('#sidebar').offset().top;
    var origBottom = origTop + $('#sidebar').height();

    var scrollDir = 0;
    var scrollLast = 0;

    var weirdOffset = -8;

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        var curTop = $('#sidebar').offset().top;
        var curBottom = curTop + $('#sidebar').height();

        if(scrollTop > scrollLast) {
            scrollDir = 1;
        } else if(scrollTop < scrollLast) {
            scrollDir = 0;
        }
        scrollLast = scrollTop;

        if(scrollDir == 1) {
            if(scrollBottom >= origBottom && scrollBottom >= curBottom) {
                $('#sidebar').animate({
                    top: scrollBottom -  $('#sidebar').outerHeight() + weirdOffset
                }, 0);
            }
        }

        if(scrollDir == 0) {
            if(scrollTop <= origTop) {

                $('#sidebar').css('top', (origTop + weirdOffset) + 'px');

            } else if(scrollTop <= curTop) {

                $('#sidebar').animate({
                    top: scrollTop + weirdOffset
                }, 0);

            }
        }
    });
});
```

The only thing I noticed is that for some reason I have an offset of 8px that I compensate for using the weirdOffset variable. Still not bad quick solution, albeit a few months later ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen one that does just that, but there are a number of plugins out there that you could put this together pretty quickly by configuring them on your page...

Take a look at http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/ it has features you could build this with pretty quickly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to scroll items at different speeds some frameworks may be overkill. You can bind a function to the scroll event (***$(document).ready(function(){});***) and manually set top positions by multiplying the scroll value by a pre-defined factor.

There are a couple of tutorials on how to do this [here](http://f6design.com/journal/2011/08/06/build-a-parallax-scrolling-website-interface-with-jquery-and-css/) and [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/).

From the first tutorial, this function is called when scrolling is detected and moves absolutely positioned elements at different speeds, giving a sense of depth and perspective:

```
function parallaxScroll(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#parallax-bg1').css('top',(0-(scrolled*.25))+'px');
    $('#parallax-bg2').css('top',(0-(scrolled*.5))+'px');
    $('#parallax-bg3').css('top',(0-(scrolled*.75))+'px');
}
```

It may be a simpler solution :)