# How do I create a custom scrollbar for fixed position sidebar in a fluid Twitter Bootstrap layout?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an article page which uses a fluid layout based on Twitter Bootstrap.

The top nav bar becomes fixed when it is at the top of the browser window (so that it sticks) using this technique:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1810-Creating-A-Sometimes-Fixed-Position-Element-With-jQuery.htm

The sidebar also becomes fixed at the same time using the above technique and using the answer in this thread:

[Fixed sidebar navigation in fluid twitter bootstrap 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350818/fixed-sidebar-navigation-in-fluid-twitter-bootstrap-2-0)

The scroll bar appears to the right of the sidebar as expected once the nav bar is at the top of the browser window, however I want to create a custom scrollbar similar to these examples:

http://readwrite.com/2012/11/07/how-technology-will-fare-in-president-obamas-second-term

http://thenextweb.com/apple/2012/11/03/apple-hides-samsung-apology-on-its-uk-site-so-it-cant-be-seen-without-scrolling/

I've tried using a technique like

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

but without success. Also because the top nav bar is fixed and his `50px` high, the fixed side bar's scroll bar extends beyond view at the bottom because of the `"top:50px;"`attribute.

Here is the demo I have created:

http://jsfiddle.net/iagdotme/uvp8t/

How can I create the custom scrollbar effect as used in The Next Web or the other example and fix the height issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TNW utilizes a plugin called [Tiny Scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar) and ReadWrite uses [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com). Have you tried either of those? Please consider working up something on jsFiddle with one of those and then re-post if the height issue remains.

And once you get jScrollPane working, here is some CSS to get you started on the custom scroller:

```
.scroll-pane
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.jspVerticalBar, .jspTrack {
    background:none;
}


.jspDrag {
   background:#ccc;
   border-radius:10px;
}
```

Used in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/m7eKD/

Comment: Thanks. I tried these plugins before, but it is encouraging to know that these websites use these plugins. Unfortunately I couldn't get them to work last time and I still can't. I have created a new jsFiddle forked from the previous one but adding in jScrollPane. The scrollbar does not show- I am getting the classes `jspContainer` and `jspContainer` added but not the scrollbar classes `jspVerticalBar` etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Oops, it would help if I actually linked to the new jsFiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/iagdotme/tGNfS/

Comment: For starters, it doesn't appear that you've included the jScrollPane CSS per http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#usage.

Comment: I thought I had- it's in the CSS frame (i.e. I haven't added it in the resources)

Comment: If you added the CSS, you'll either need to provide a new fiddle link or save the current version as your base. The fiddle above still doesn't include the appropriate CSS (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css).

Comment: Aggh, sorry- having connection problems. This fiddle should work- http://jsfiddle.net/iagdotme/tGNfS/2/

Comment: Listen, you've got too much going on here. Try debugging from the bottom up. Start by making sure you can get jScrollPane working (e.g., http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/m7eKD/), then start incrementally adding in your additional features until you identify exactly where and when the problems start to occur. You'll save yourself a lot of grays hairs by using this approach...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my answer at this post ([Parallax sidebar scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078800/parallax-sidebar-scrolling/15168139#15168139)) which reproduces the sidebar scrolling behavior you see used on readwrite.com.

Comment: Thanks for this- looks like a great solution! Really excited about giving it a whirl. I did sort out my problem although it took some time and it's not perfect but do have a look and let me know. My website is http://iag.me/ - the menu effect is on the article pages- so just click on one of them. Thanks again!