# how to implement parallax scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, parallax

this is link For reference
http://readwrite.com/2013/02/07/robert-scoble-favorite-apps-facebook-gmail-youtube

in this site Center and Right Section both are scrolled at a time if we scroll Center section...

i am done it same with this code:-

this is html code:-

```
<div id="left" class="linked">
<img height="600" src="http://www.visitingdc.com/images/eiffel-tower-picture.jpg">
</div>
<div id="right" class="linked">
<img  src="http://www.visitingdc.com/images/eiffel-tower-picture.jpg">
</div><br>
```

Script:-

```
$(function(){

    $('.linked').scroll(function(){
        $('.linked').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());    
    })

})
```

css:-

```
<br>#left { width: 300px; height: 400px; overflow: scroll; float: left; }
#right { width: 300px; height: 400px; overflow: scroll; float: left; }
```

but i have one little bit problem.
in above site both scroll at a time but the Right side is Scrolling slow how its work....?
Please help me...

Comment: its called parallax scrolling...

Comment: @Vloxxity great thanks man... how its possible any idea?

Comment: i told you how it is called so you could google yourself an answer xD

Comment: How does this question relate to PHP?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078800/parallax-sidebar-scrolling/15168139#15168139

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/cuVC7/0/

Please take a look at this solution. Though not very universal, it can give you a nice start. The speed of the right `div` is adjusted automatically as you change its height in CSS part of the fiddle.

It should be noted that 2D-parallax-related problems like this one require knowledge of basic math.  Sample above uses this model:

- Determine the scroll of the page, so we know how much left `div` is scrolled.
- Use knowledge of height of the page, window height and height of the left `div` to calculate *relative scroll*. That is, the value from 0 to 1 showing us whether the page is not scrolled at all, scrolled by some amount, or scroll to the end.
- Map the *relatve scroll* to the dimensions of *slow layer* with respect of window size to determine exact scroll for *slow layer*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite the scrolling behaviour of one of those divs (in js), and set it to e.g. 0.5 of the other one.
Take a look here:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/